# How to access specific types of values from variable argument in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I an writing a function that accepts the order placed by the customer.The function should check whether the items requested are present in the menu i am passing the order into a variable argument as every menu will be different so how can i check if the requested dish is available in menu or not from variable argument?

```
menu = ('Veg Roll', 'Noodles', 'Fried Rice', 'Soup')

def place_order(*item_tuple):
    if item_tuple in menu:
        print("Available")
    else
        print("Item not Available")


place_order("Veg Roll","Noodles")


Sample Input:("Veg Roll","Noodles")
Sample Output:Available Available
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to do

```
def place_order(*item_tuple):
    for item in item_tuple:
        if item in menu:
            print("Available")
        else:
            print("Item not Available")
```

If you care about the space between the Available prints, you can change the line to `print("Available", end=" ")`

Answer (score 0):

## API

You have defined a curious API.
Better to define `def place_order(items)`, without the `*` star,
and require callers to supply a tuple:

```
place_order(('Veg Roll', 'Noodles'))
```

## algorithm

You want to test each item independently:

```
def item_available(item):
    return item in menu

def items_available(items):
    return all(map(item_available, items))

def place_order(items):
    if not items_available(items):
        print("At least one item is not ", end="")
    print("Available")
```

Additionally, if the menu grows in size
then it will be faster to model it with a `set` rather than a `tuple`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to iterate through the items in the list.

```
def place_order(*item_tuple):
    for i in item_tuple:
        if item_tuple in menu:
            print("Available")
        else
            print("Item not Available")
```

or even more pythonic

```
def place_order(*item_tuple):
    [print(f"{'Available' if i in menu else 'Item not available'}") for i in item_tuple]
```